# Can't boot Ubuntu 13.04 after installing alongside Windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, grub-efi

I've tried running boot-repair a few times with diffrent settings, to no avail.

- [paste.ubuntu.com/5948482](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5948482)
- [paste.ubuntu.com/5948580](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5948580)
- [paste.ubuntu.com/5948657](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5948657)

When an option does appear in the BIOS to boot from 'Hard Drive', [I get a line of random ascii characters](https://www.dropbox.com/s/66yz2r70k1io5bb/Foto%2004.08.13%2018%2056%2013.jpg)

I've also tried using EasyBCD, but that give an error too.

I have an Asrock Z77 Extreme 4 motherboard.

Thanks.

Comment: Your hard drive could be corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, enter your firmware setup utility (what most people think of as "the BIOS," although it isn't technically a BIOS) and [disable Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) (Unfortunately, how to do this varies from one system to another, so you'll have to dig to find the right options.) It's conceivable that this will get things working, but I can make no promises about that. If it doesn't, I recommend you try preparing a CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) There are download links for both of those on the site. Try booting from that. If it gives you working boot options for both Ubuntu and Windows, you can go ahead and install it to your hard disk. Installing the Debian package is the easiest way to do this.